# I want to give feedback to users after they uninstall and re install the app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to give feedback to a user if they've installed an app before. Once they uninstall the app they have been wiped from the database. I'm using flutter but the question is more native specific. I'm thinking keychain/keystore but not sure how to do a check. I wondering can I use my unique  package name(android) and bundle identifier(iOS)? How can I check on iOS and android if an app has been installed before?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can use the keychain and at the first run of you app, you check if the Keychain Value exists.

On android you can use the Keystore for this. But don't save things like private keys in there, for this use. Maybe something like `appXYwasinstalled`